# Excel VBA: Resetting CurrentRow when working with multiple tables

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a user form that interacts with several tables in a workbook. The form is split up into different section and uses spin buttons to scroll through records and display currently entered data to allow the user to modify and update records accordingly. The only issue I am having is that if I am on a record in another table and toggle to a different table that has less records, I get an our of range error. I have tried to reset the range and set the row to the first row in the table, however, both methods have failed. I am not sure how to fix this. Any ideas? Below is my code for the spin buttons and the update caption function.

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp()
    
    Sheet1.Activate
        
    Set HousekeepingTable = Sheet1.ListObjects("Housekeeping")
       
    If HousekeepingTable.ListRows.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub
    
    If CurrentRow > 1 Then
        
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow - 1
           
        UpdateHousekeepingRecord
    
    End If
    

End Sub

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown()

    Sheet1.Activate
      
    Set HousekeepingTable = Sheet1.ListObjects("Housekeeping")
        
    If CurrentRow = HousekeepingTable.ListRows.Count Then Exit Sub

    If CurrentRow < HousekeepingTable.ListRows.Count Then
    
        CurrentRow = CurrentRow + 1
          
        UpdateHousekeepingRecord
    
    End If

End Sub
```

```
Private Sub UpdateHousekeepingRecord()

    With HousekeepingTable
    
        Sheet1.Activate
        Sheet1.ListObjects("Housekeeping").ListRows(1).Range.Select
        Label15.Caption = CurrentRow & " of " & .ListRows.Count
        PopulateHousekeeping .ListRows(CurrentRow).Range
        .ListRows(CurrentRow).Range.Select
        
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by adding an If statement to set the current row to the total count of the rows in the specified table.

```
        If CurrentRow > HousekeepingTable.ListRows.Count Then
        CurrentRow = HousekeepingTable.ListRows.Count
        End If
```